# Ocultar/Mostrar TextBox cuando cambia el valor de otro TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en `WPF` y me topé con un pequeño problema.

Quiero que cuando se cambie el valor de un `TextBox`, se desaparezcan o aparezcan otros `TextBox`, dependiendo del valor del `TextBox` que se esta cambiando, estoy utilizando el patrón `MVVM` y ya intenté con la propiedad `ObservableCollection<T>` pero no me está actualizando los datos en el `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de lograrlo, te mostraré una:

Primero tu ViewModel debe implementar `INotifyPropertyChanged` para que comunique los cambios hasta la interfaz de usuario, de lo contrario estos no se reflejarán.

```
public MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 //...
}
```

Ahora agrega estas 2 lineas para ayudarte a lanzar este evento:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Ahora bien, al "*TextBox1*" hazle binding a su propiedad "Text" a una propiedad de tipo string en el ViewModel,

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding TextBox1Text, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"/>
```

y un TextBox "*TextBox2*" hazle binding a su propiedad `Visibility` a una propiedad de tipo "Visibility" en el ViewModel

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Visibility="{Binding TextBox2Visibility, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"/>
```

Las propiedades en el ViewModel deben quedar así:

```
private string _textBox1Text;
public string TextBox1Text
{
    get { return _textBox1Text; }
    set 
    {
        _textBox1Text = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TextBox1Text");
    }
}

private Visibility _textBox2Visibility;
public Visibility TextBox2Visibility
{
     get { return _textBox2Visibility; }
     set
     { 
        _textBox2Visibility = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("TextBox2Visibility");
     }
}
```

Luego en la propiedad string que está bindeada al `TextboX1` agrégale luego del set una linea que sea el nombre de un método, debe quedar asi:

```
private string _textBox1Text;
public string TextBox1Text
{
    get { return _textBox1Text; }
   set
   { 
      _textBox1Text = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("TextBox1Text");
      VerificarValor(value);
   }
}

private void VerificarValor(string value)
{
  if(value.equals("clave"))
  {
    TextBox2Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  }
  else 
  {
     TextBox2Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //o collapsed
  }
}
```

Y sigues la misma lógica para hacer aparecer o desaparecer el resto de los TextBox.

Otra forma sería Bindear la propiedad `Visibility` en XAML de cada TextBox a la propiedad `Text` del TextBox que contendrá la palabra clave.. y luego agregarle en el binding la referencia a un Converter que devuelva el valor de `Visibility` según el contenido que reciba, en este caso el texto del Textbox.

Si bien los Converters te dan un código mas ordenado y "standard", yo prefiero en este caso manejarlo directo en el ViewModel pues entrega más control ya que puedes manipular a gusto las condiciones.

Comment: Gracias!!!, era justo lo que estaba buscando y funciona muy bien :)